# Custom target URL for Views content pane exposed filter (block)

Tags: 7, views

Here is the situation:

There are 2 pages in Page manager

1. Overridden page of the Taxonomy term (i.e. Path: /%term )
2. Page with Taxonomy term filters (i.e. Path: /%term/filter )

And a View with 2 displays (content panes) :

1. Show all from term
2. Show filtered (with exposed filters in block).

How to place the exposed filter block on /%term page but when the filter is submitted,  redirect and apply it to the /%term/filter path ?

Thank you

Comment: awesome video helper for hook_form_alter: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syqsH2CEu6U&t=14m42s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use form redirection in [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#comment-18139).